# Вызов метода из шаблона Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Разбираюсь с vue, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Не знаю как вызвать метод из шаблона template. Есть следующий код
HTML с двумя компонентами.

```
  <input-box
    v-bind:password='password'>
    <button v-on:click='changePassword'>new pass</button>
    <button v-on:click='copyPassword'>copyPassword</button>
  </input-box>

  <range-slider>
    <input v-on:change="changePassword" type="range" min="5" max="10" step="1">
  </range-slider>
```

И соответственно js-код

```
Vue.component('input-box', {
    props: ['password'],
  template: 
    `<div>
        <input v-bind:value="password"></input>
        <slot></slot>
     </div>`
});

Vue.component('range-slider', {
    props: ['changePassword'],
  template: 
    `<div>
        <input v-on:change="changePassword" type="range" min="5" max="10" step="1"> /* Не работает */
        <slot></slot>
     </div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#input-box',
  data: {
        password: 'qwerty123'
  },
  methods: {
    changePassword: function() {
        this.password = Math.round(Math.random()*1000000);
    },
    copyPassword: function() {
        alert(this.password);
    }
  }
});
```

Что можно сделать, чтобы вызвать метод changePassword экземпляра 
input-box' непосредственно в компоненте range-slider?
[jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/rz158hgw/1/)

Comment: Есть во Vue важный паттерн - односторонний поток данный. Изучи его (в разделе про компоненты) и не будешь писать код, который сам с трудом понимаешь. В компоненты передаешь параметры и слушаешь события от них

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переделал: https://jsfiddle.net/rz158hgw/4/

```
<input v-on:change="$emit('change')" type="range" min="5" max="10" step="1">
```

Подробней как сделать что Вам надо [тут](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-v-model-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0).